# VS2010 Compile Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Apologies.  I am sure I should know where to look to deal with this but I do not:

The error below has appeared in my solution.  I am not aware of why.

> The item
>   "obj\Release\ScruffyDuck.AirportDesignEditor.MainForm.resources" was
>   specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate
>   items are not supported by the "Resources" parameter. Airport Design
>   Editor

Perhaps someone would be kind enough to put me out of my misery and tell me where to look.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found it.  I have no idea how it happened.  However it might be useful for the future.  MainForm has a number of files containing different parts of the class. The main part has all the designer code and so on.  Somehow a .resx file got created on one of the partial class files along with an InitializeComponent() method.  Removing the extra .resx file got as far as reporting the duplicate method and removing that allowed the solution to compile again.  It seems that though the file names are different (the error was in MainForm.EventHandlers) the two resx files are treated as the same even though they have different names.

I am now getting some exceptions but at least I can get the code running in the debugger again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to open your .csproj file, and look for that file name.  It sounds like ScruffyDuck.AirportDesignEditor.MainForm.resources is appearing more than once.  Just remove the duplicate node (.csproj files are just xml).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find that in the .csproj file - only MainForm.resx and that appears only once

Answer (score 0):

1. Just  remove **obj** directory from HD manually.
2. Clear solution from Visual Studio (Right click on project in SolutionExplorer and select "Clear")
3. Rebuild solution.

Cause could be a fault of generated resource file, due some conflicts happened in your project.

*Should* work.

Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately not.   I deleted the obj file for that project.  Cleaned the solution and built it again.  Same error.  I get the same error whether I build in Debug or Release mode

Comment: I just did a file search for files containing mainform.resources and a text search for this in the files in this solution.  Only one turns up in obj\debug (which I tried to compile after cleaning the solution

Comment: wait... I mean do not delete obj FILE, but obj DIRECTORY. Did you delete obj DIRECTORY? cause you wrote " I deleted the obj file "

Comment: Yes I deleted the obj directory. It contains a Debug sub folder and a Release sub folder.  I have only a single copy of the file referred to in each.  I cannot find a duplicate anywhere.  So I wonder if there is another file referencing this however I cannot find it in a text search

Comment: Sometimes helps also, after steps I described, but before rebuild, to close and reopen solution.